# Documentation Review Error on Approval

Tags: bug, documentation-proposals

After clicking "**Approve Change**" for change request:
https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/117297

I am given an error:

> An error has occurred - please try your action again.

This review task has been showing for over 30 minutes now.

Is there a possible bug with this item?

---

**Screenshot:**

[image: Error]